# Weyl's Dimension Formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I'm trying to grasp how Weyl's Dimension Formula works, and I'm having a bit of trouble.

As an example, I was trying to calculate the dimension of V($\varepsilon_1$) for gl(3).

First, I set the positive roots to be the set {$\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2 , \varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_3$}, and thus, I set $\rho$ (the half-sum of positive roots) to be $\frac12(2\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2 - \varepsilon_3)$. So then, I go ahead, and put that in my formula;
$$\prod_{\text{set of positive roots}} \frac{(\lambda + \rho, \text{positive root})}{(\rho, \text{positive root})}$$
$$ = \frac{(\varepsilon_1 + \frac12(2\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2 - \varepsilon_3), (\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2))}{(\frac12(2\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2 - \varepsilon_3), (\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2))} \frac{(\varepsilon_1 + \frac12(2\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2 - \varepsilon_3), (\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_3))}{(\frac12(2\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2 - \varepsilon_3), (\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_3))}$$
$$= \frac{(2\varepsilon_1 - \frac12\varepsilon_2 - \frac12\varepsilon_3), (\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2))}{((\varepsilon_1 - \frac12\varepsilon_2 - \frac12\varepsilon_3), (\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2))} \frac{((2\varepsilon_1 - \frac12\varepsilon_2 - \frac12\varepsilon_3), (\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_3))}{((\varepsilon_1 - \frac12\varepsilon_2 - \frac12\varepsilon_3), (\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_3))}$$

However, from here, I'm not actually sure what to do. I understand that, with inner products, $(\varepsilon_i, \varepsilon_j) = \delta_{i,j}$, but I can't work out how to use that here. I mean, if I were to do that, taking, for example, $(2\varepsilon_1 - \frac12\varepsilon_2 - \frac12\varepsilon_3), (\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2))$, does that become $2 + \frac12$ ?? In the example given in class, for the dimension of V$(\varepsilon_1)$, my lecturer seemed to use that train of logic, but I'm honestly a bit uncertain.

Any help would be fantastic!!

Comment: It will probably be easier if you write your weight as a linear combination of the fundamental weights. That way, when you write the roots, it is easy to see what the various inner products become. (recall that $\rho$ is the sum of the fundamental weights).

Comment: BTW, it is supposed to be a $\rho$ in the formula, not a $p$. Putting a $p$ could cause confusion as this formula also works in characteristic $p$ (though no longer for the simple modules).

Comment: Ohh, and a final comment: You forgot one of the positive roots ($\varepsilon_2 - \varepsilon_3$).

Comment: Why is $(\varepsilon_2 - \varepsilon_3)$ also one of the roots?? I was under the impression that we were only using $\varepsilon_1$, and could only take things away from that??

Comment: No, you need to take this product over all the positive roots. Note that both numerator and denominator includes $\rho$ which has non-zero inner product with each of the positive roots, so you cannot ignore any of them.

Comment: Thank you for all of this clarification.

Just to try and wrap my head around this a bit more, I've gone back and written everything out in terms of fundamental weight. I may have this confused, but, would it be correct to write $(2\varepsilon_1 - \frac12\varepsilon_2 - \frac12\varepsilon_3), (\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2))$ as $(2, -\frac12, -\frac12), (1, -1, 0)$ ??

Comment: Those are not the fundamental weights. Actually, the fundamental weights may not be the best choice here, as it is $gl(3)$ rather than $sl(3)$. But to clarify, the fundamental weights are the ones whose inner products with the simple roots are either $1$ or $0$ (so for each simple root, you have a fundamental weight which has inner product $1$ with that root and $0$ with the others).

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. I kind of understand how my lecturer did one of our examples now - would you mind if I worked out the dimension for this question, and checked it with you??

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: I ended up with a dimension of 3 - does that sound correct??

Comment: Yes, the simple module in question is actually the standard $gl(3)$-module (ie, the matrices act on $\mathbb{C}^3$ via the usual multiplication).

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help - I was just being an absolute idiot when it came to Euclidean inner products. Completely slipped my mind. :P

Comment: Glad to help. Now, for an extra example, try with the weight $\rho$.

Comment: I ended up with a dimension of 8. Would that be correct??

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: To remove this question from the unanswered list, I would suggest you add an answer yourself, where you put the details of the calculations (this will probably also be helpful for later visitors trying to understand the formula, and of course, it might earn you a bit of reputation in the process).